# draw a circle within a square while dragging a mouse

Tags: graphics2d

I'm not having a good day I think, and I'm struggling with an issue I think it should be easy.

I have to draw a circle while dragging the mouse. The users clicks and holds, drags the mouse, and release the button.

But:

1) I have the coordinates of the mousedown event, and the current ones (x1, y1, x2, y2). This ones defines a rectangle.

2) (x1, y1) must be the center of the circle, and it radius must be the distance between x1, y1 and the current ones.

3) I have to show the current radius (the value; not the line itself).

4) The user must be able to draw the circle dragging left, right, upwards, downwards, and any intermediate combination.

Thank you very much!

PS: As an option (example, if the user drags while shift key is pressed), the rectangle should be a square and a circle should be drawn instead of an oval.

Comment: are you sure that (x1,x2) is the center? that sounds a bit wrong to me

Comment: thank you very much, @VamsidharReddyGaddam. it was wrong indeed.

Comment: is this a pseudo-code kind of question, or would you mind telling us in what language you plan to implement this?

Comment: I'm forced to do it using Windev. Pseudocode is enough; I'll adapt it.

Comment: That was the confusion. If you want to have the center of the circle at x1, y1 and if you want the circle to be inside the square (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) - it is not possible.

Comment: I know; it was a typo writing the question. Thank you very much anyways for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(wagering that 0,0 is left upper corner otherwise invert 1 and 2; x1/y1 is buttondown is center)

radius  = sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)

x_leftuppercorner = x1 - radius

y_leftuppercorner = y1 - radius

x_rightlowercorner = x1 + radius

y_rightlowercorner = y1 + radius

dCircle(x_luc, y_luc, x_ruc, y_ruc)